# Form's Rendered attribute causing Ajax issues

Tags: primefaces

I’m having a strange problem. I'm trying to put multiple forms on a modal dialog and have only one form visible at a time based on a flag, dynamically switching from one form to another in response to a user action.  The problem is that by adding a rendered attribute to the form causes Ajax events to fail calling the serverside methods in the backing bean.

The following form and backing bean are simplified copy, but it demonstrate the issue. Basically, if rendered="#{requestScope.shouldRender}" is removed from the h:form id="form2" and when you enter in the text field, everything works as expected and the text will be displayed on the console. If adding rendered="#{requestScope.shouldRender}" to the h:form id="form2" component, then the method is not called at all.

The environment is:
Primefaces 3.3
Spring 3.0
Websphere server 7

Here is an example form with the rendered attribute (remove to make it work properly):

```
 <h:body>
        <h:form id="form1">
              <p:commandButton id="showButton" value="Show" update=":panel1">
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{true}"
                          target="#{requestScope.shouldRender}" />
              </p:commandButton>
        </h:form>

        <p:outputPanel id="panel1">
              <h:form id="form2" rendered="#{requestScope.shouldRender}">
                    <p:inputText id="fn" value="#{testBean.fn}">
                          <p:ajax event="keyup" listener="#{testBean.valueChangeListener}" />
                    </p:inputText>
              </h:form>
        </p:outputPanel>
  </h:body>
```

Here is a little backing bean:

```
    @Component
    @Scope("request")
    public class TestBean {
  private String fn;

  public void setFn(String fn) {
        this.fn = fn;
  }

  public String getFn() {
        return fn;
  }

  public void valueChangeListener() {
        System.out.println(fn);
  }
```

}

Comment: why you need two separate forms? Have you tried putting them on the same form?